# Accessibility for Gridview and combobox in windows 8.1 metro apps XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

Below is the code using in my application, for accessibility to read my combobox using screen reader.

Actually its reading the item, but reading the location where i have given viewmodel path for every combobox item.

```
<ComboBox  Style="{Binding OpportunityTypeStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedType,Mode=TwoWay}"
           AutomationProperties.IsRequiredForForm="True" 
          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="True" AutomationProperties.Name="Name"
           ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding TypeErrorMessage}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding OpportunityTypeChangedCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Width="400" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding }" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: By _"screen reader"_ do you mean Narrator?

Comment: Yes, Narrator only !

Comment: Hi, Any solution on this.